# 3.6V cell in 3.7V 18650 protected battery?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

I am not an electrical engineer, so my question might be dumb.

I needed an unprotected 3.7V 18650 battery replacement, but at that time there were only protected ones and I bought one because it is not so difficult to remove the protection.

The **protected battery was labeled 3.7V**, but when I removed the shrink wrap to remove the protection board, **there was a 3.6V cell inside**.

**My question is, is this OK in the case of using a protection scheme *(e.g., IDK, the protection circuit raises the voltage or changes the internal resistance of the entire assembly, or it doesn't matter at all)* or just a fraud by the manufacturer *(inside a protected 3.7V battery, there must be a cell of exactly 3.7V)*?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Rechargeable cells do not have a fixed voltage. Both 3.6 V and 3.7 V are valid nominal voltages for a Lithium Ion cell, which can range from (about) 2.8 V when completely empty to (about) 4.2 V when fully charged. Your 3.6 V cell is unlikely to be a "fraud", just inconsistent labeling. The question is why you need to remove the protection circuit.

Comment: @StarCat, thanks for the comment! I removed the protection circuit because I needed to replace a dead battery in some device and it was also without a protection circuit and the battery with a protection circuit did not fit in size. But it was the only option available for purchase at that time.

Answer (score 0):

[The first 4 digits of the designation “18650” indicate the physical dimensions](https://www.18650batterystore.com/collections/18650-batteries).

18650 can contain many different [Chemistry](https://commonsensehome.com/18650-battery/), that decides the voltage.

3.7V is nominal voltage for Li-polymer, and 3.6V is for Li-ion, according to [this website](https://components101.com/batteries/18650-lithium-cell).

Your battery cell is Li-ion. Please be careful using it [without protection circuitry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMy2_qNO2Y0). Keep it far away from other people.

Comment: I disagree that 3.6V is the nominal voltage for an older Lithium-ion cell. Li-PO and Lithium-Ion are the same chemistry, 4.2V when fully charged and 3.2V when discharged. Then the average (nominal) voltage is (4.2 + 3.2)/2= 3.7V.

Comment: @Audioguru , A good information! I do not agree nor disagree with the voltage theory of [that site](https://components101.com/batteries/18650-lithium-cell), but telling how people consider "the Voltage of a single cell May represents a specific Chemistry".